# Error: connect ENETUNREACH 0.0.0.2:80 in postman tool

Tags: postman

[having issue while getting response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfxZr.png)

[this the dropbox API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0TpJ.png)

I'm new to this tool I don't know how to get a response, how to give a request. please if anybody could answer my question it will be helpful for me to go more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add domain to URL

Example:

```
https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/file_requests/list
```

[image]

Run request in postman

[image]

Comment: after entered url i have got an error( Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: https. is not in the cert's altnames: )